# How to handle queries that return different values for nested objects in subqueries in graphql with apollo client

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client

I have a schema like

```
type Worklog {
  id: ID!
  started: String!
  timeSpentSeconds: Int!
  user: String!
}

type Issue {
   id: ID!
   worklogs: [Worklog!]
   user: String!
}

Query {
    issuesForCurrentUser():[Issue!]
    issuesForAllUsers():[Issue!]
}
```

The problem is that

- `issuesForCurrentUser()` should only return issues that belong to the current user as well as all worklogs that belong to the current user for that issue
- `issuesForAllUsers()` should return all issues and all worklogs for each each regardless of the user.

That is, for the same issue id there may be different numbers of worklogs returned depending on the query.

I get the following warning from apollo client.

```
Cache data may be lost when replacing the worklogs field of a Issue object.

To address this problem (which is not a bug in Apollo Client), define a custom merge function for the Issue.worklogs field, so InMemoryCache can safely merge these objects:
```

I can understand what is going on here. The graph is normalized and the cache sees a new result come in with an id and matches against an existing cache entry. The worklogs field of the existing cache entry do not match. Hence the warning. Merging is not the right answer as I really do want different results for different queries rather than accumulate the results together.

I think my use case is clear but I'm muddled on the architecture.

Comment: one query should be sufficient ... no user param, return all ... for this case use https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#customizing-identifier-generation-globally to make issue id user related

Comment: It's not quite like that. An issue '25' can belong to 'sally' but a worklog for issue '25' can belong to 'bob' So the same issue is being returned each time with different numbers of worklogs. So in one case I get issue '25' with all of sally's worklogs and for the other query I get issues '25' with all of bob's worklogs.

Comment: return some additional 'queriedUser' (or simple 'user', opposite to 'owner') field (to create unique key with or without id) in issue type (resolved from parent arg)

Comment: Ok. Next time I'll that. Instead I've decided not to fight the system and rearranged the queries so that I can queries worklogs or issues and worklogs contains issues which contain worklogs and it works much better that way.